Rust HashMap supporting pointer stability to allow key referencing its value
In Rust, using a HashMap where the key is a &str that refers to a String member within its corresponding value is not directly possible. The following example illustrates the idea:
type PersonMap = HashMap<&str, Person>;

struct Person {
    name: String,
}

This is not feasible due to Rust's ownership and borrowing rules and HashMap's resizing, as explained in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61021022/84540).
However, I wonder if there exists an unordered map implementation that supports pointer stability (What is pointer stability?), which could make such usage possible. Or is it not possible due to Rust's lifetime checking? Thanks.

What would happen if someone were to mutate the value in-place with get_mut?

You do not need pointer stability to support such a mapping, even without cloning keys. The trick is to use HashSet instead with a wrapper that makes its value behave like its key.
Here's how that could look:
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    // other fields
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct PersonByName(Person);

impl PartialEq for PersonByName {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0.name == other.0.name
    }
}

impl Eq for PersonByName {}

impl Hash for PersonByName {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.0.name.hash(state);
    }
}

impl Borrow<str> for PersonByName {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0.name
    }
}

fn main() {
    let people = vec![
        Person { name: "Jimmy".to_owned() },
        Person { name: "Timmy".to_owned() },
        Person { name: "Lenny".to_owned() },
    ];
    
    let map: HashSet<PersonByName> = people.into_iter().map(PersonByName).collect();
    
    println!("{:?}", map.get("Timmy"));
}

Some(PersonByName(Person { name: "Timmy" }))

Playground link
So even though its a "set" and not a "map", we can treat it like a map by making use Rust's Borrow trait when .get-ing a value. The Hash and PartialEq/Eq are there to make it behave like just a string so the HashSet lookup is consistent.

That's a cool idea. Never thought of this. Thanks.

Theoretically, even String provides pointer stability, since if it moves its content won't move (although the aliasing questions are still in dilemma).
Practically, pointer stability is not enough. It is enough for the code to not have UB, but it is not enough for it to pass the borrow checker. The borrow checker doesn't allow self-referential structs, and it doesn't care about pointer stability.
I'm not implying that a map that allows self-referential structs can't be written (it probably can, but it will involve many soundness holes). Maybe it was even already written. But if such map exists, it will need to be written from the beginning to deal with self-referential map. This is not "just another map" that supports value-referencing keys, at its very bones this is its goal.
If you are looking for how to write such map, you can draw inspiration from the many existing self-referential crates. I imagine such map would have a design similar to one of them, just tailored to map instead of a generic struct.

As already mentioned, this isn't possible because even if the address were stable, it wouldn't be sufficient to ensure the string was never deallocated while the reference existed.
But for situations like this, where you want to use the same value in two places, shared ownership is an option; you would use Arc<str> or Rc<str> instead of String.
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Arc;

pub type PersonMap = HashMap<Arc<str>, Person>;

pub struct Person {
    name: Arc<str>,
}

pub fn insert(map: &mut PersonMap, person: Person) {
    map.insert(person.name.clone(), person);
}

This is not as efficient as the PersonByName option in kmdreko’s answer, because it stores extra pointers, but it is simple and applicable to a wide variety of possible data structures.

The reason for the invalidity is that the compiler does not know how long the owner will live. For this reason it considers the reference to be invalid. You can force the compiler (with the lifetime concept) to consider that two references have the same lifetime
Example:
use std::collections::HashMap;
struct Person {
    name: String,
}
impl Person {
    fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        Self { name }
    }
    fn ref_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }
}
type PersonMap<'a> = HashMap<&'a str, &'a Person>;
fn main() {
    let mut person_map: PersonMap = HashMap::new();
    let person = Person::new("name".to_string());
    person_map.insert(person.ref_name(), &person);
}


That's not answering the question: the OP wants to store the Persons themselves in the HashMap (i.e. HashMap<_, Person>), but you're only storing references to the Persons (i.e. HashMap<_, &Person>)
